# AS3 Unit Testing Frameworks or Libraries

Tags: flash, unit-testing, frameworks

What are the best unit testing frameworks or libraries for AS3 programming?  Specifically for projects that do not involve Flex, only Flash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit Testing AS3 Code for Flash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909959/unit-testing-as3-code-for-flash)

Comment: The intent of posting these two questions separate was to focus this post on tools and technologies, and the other on methods and philosophy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is http://asunit.org/ which works with AS2/AS3 only porojects and more.
FlexUnit http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexunit/FlexUnit also works with AS3 only projects.

Comment: Why would you choose one over the other?

Comment: I never did use ASUnit myself, so I can't really compare it to FlexUnit.

Answer (score 0):

you also have ASTUce
https://code.google.com/p/astuce/

no dependency on Flex, no dependency on Events
will work only with synchronous tests (on purpose)

and work purely and truely on the command line
https://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/issues/detail?id=40
https://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/issues/detail?id=41

so you can add it in your build script, here an example
https://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/source/browse/tags/1.0.2/build.xml#153

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I made this.

AS3 Unit: 
https://github.com/Hoten/as3unit